# What data structure is best suited for quickly searchable text data?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

When looking at products like DnD Insider and the Kindle app, users can quickly search for matching text strings in a large structure of text data. If I were to make a web application that allowed users to quickly search a "rulebook" (or similar text) for a matching entry and pull up the data to read, how should I organize the data?

I don't think it's a good idea to put all the data into memory. But if I stored it in some kind of database, what would be a good way to search the database and retrieve the appropriate matching entry?

So far, I believe I'm going to use the Boyer-Moore algorithm to actually do the searching. I can put the various sections of rule-text  into different database entries. The user search will prioritize searching section titles over section body text. Since the text will be static and not user-editable, perhaps an array to store every word would work?

Comment: How big is your text really? For reference even the bible (KJV) is only about 4MB

Comment: You can try ElasticSearch. You can check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) for more details.

Comment: Have you looked into suffix arrays and suffix trees?

Comment: Ternary Search Tries are an efficient data structure space and time wise.

Comment: How large is your data, and how often does it change? Are you looking for full text search, or just phrase search? That is, if you searched for "blue goose", would it match "blue spruce goose"? Do you want to handle fuzzy search, so that if somebody searched for "blew goose", it would still match "blue goose"? What are your data storage limitations? What is your expected traffic? What is your expected response time? You need to provide us a whole lot more information before we can give you anything approaching a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically some kind of *inverted index* is used for this purpose:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

Basically this is a map from each word to a list of the places in which it appears.   Each "place" could be a (document ID, occurrence count), or something more precise if you want to support phrase searching or if you want to give more weight to matches in titles, etc.

Search results are usually ranked with some variant of tf-idf: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf